# Very Large Textures on XNA Windows Phone 7

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, xna

How well will a Windows Phone 7 XNA game handle large textures, approximately 8000 x 4000 pixels with lots of colours. For the background to my game I have the choice between making some sort of background streaming system to load small textures when they are needed or to load the background as one massive texture.

Will the phone struggle with this or will I be much better off loading and unloading smaller textures into memory when needed?

Also any format suggestions for these textures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe individual texture size you can have on a WP7 XNA application is 2048x2048. So that will be your largest texture to work with.

From my experience it's best to go with several sprite sheets, separated by their contents or whatever makes sense. I use several ranging from 512x512 to 1536x1024.

Limit of 2048 for initializing a texture listed in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd231959%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried XNA with a windows 7 phone myself but I found this article that I think could answer your question
[here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/89166.aspx).
Good Luck with your game

Comment: It's a little helpful thanks, but i'm not sure it answers the performance aspect.